# None of the products registered in the RevenueCat dashboard could be fetched from the Play Store

Tags: flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

Flutter version: 3.10.6

RevenueCat version: 5.0.3

Platfrom: Android

PlatformException(23, There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details., {code: 23, message: There is an issue with your configuration. Check the underlying error for more details., readableErrorCode: ConfigurationError, readable_error_code: ConfigurationError, underlyingErrorMessage: There's a problem with your configuration. None of the products registered in the RevenueCat dashboard could be fetched from the Play Store. More information: [https://rev.cat/why-are-offerings-empty}](https://rev.cat/why-are-offerings-empty%7D), null)

on main file:

Future _configureSDK() async {

// Enable debug logs before calling `configure`.

await Purchases.setLogLevel(LogLevel.debug);

PurchasesConfiguration configuration;

configuration = PurchasesConfiguration(StoreConfig.instance.apiKey)

..appUserID = null

..observerMode = false;

await Purchases.configure(configuration);

}

On Futurebuilder in premium page:

Future<List> configureInAppPurchase() async {

List packageList = [];

Offerings? offerings;

try {

offerings = await Purchases.getOfferings();

} on PlatformException catch (e) {

if (context.mounted) {

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(

SnackBar(

content: Text(e.message ?? "Unknown error"),

),

);

}

Someone can you help me?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, its working on iOS but not on android